# Non deterministic restarts of desktop

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, power

I have a problem with a desktop - it restarts occasionally (but without freezing). This behaviour is non deterministic - sometimes the machine works for hours while otherwise it restarts just after the windows starts up.

I tried reinstalling the system but without any help.

I was considering the power supply failure but the power supply was replaced recently with new one (unfortunately I can't recall whether it was before or after the problems occured).

Do you superusers have any ideas? I will appreciate any clues on how I can diagnose the problem (even, what can cause such problems).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I found out what was the problem (probably).

It was software problem - when I turned off automatic restarts in system settings (system properties -> advanced -> startup & recovery - uncheck 'automatically restart') xp started showing bsod (blue screen). The stop code was 0xc4 which is translated as DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION. **So it turned out it is problem with driver.**

I think this might be caused by wireless network card after installing sp3. Sp3 altered one of the libraries used by the wlan card driver (wlanapi.dll). I downloaded newest drivers from producers site and so far the problem did not appear.

I used the word probably as the problem is non deterministic and I expect that it might be other driver. Although I am pretty sure it's one of the drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably on the right idea with the power supply, random failures are usually some form of hardware failure.  Power and memory are the first things to suspect.  I'd next try [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to see if your RAM is ok.

After that I'd suspect the motherboard and CPU if your power supply is known good.  It could also be a problem with a number of other things, so it may be worth trying a Linux live CD (for example Ubuntu) to help eliminate problems with XP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ordered multimeter to ensure power supply is ok. Will check ram, motherboard and cpu next. The live cd might be indeed a good idea but the problem is that I can't tell whether linux solved the problme or is this just the working period. Anyway I do the examination.

Comment: I like the RAM idea. I had an hp nx 7000 laptop a few years back that had that widespread RAM malfunction due to production problems.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already checked this, but just in case - if your Windows Updates are set to automatically download/install, it may be rebooting legitimately.

Comment: It does not seem as Win Update - it happens way too often for updates and windows is usually asking whether to restart or not, but thanks for your response

Comment: No problem, I noticed with Win7 that I seem to miss the question box more often than not, and have had a few surprise reboots, myself.  ;)